# Using `CGEventSourceSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval` instead of the deprecated `CGSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval`

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

When programmatically moving the mouse cursor, you must set `CGSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval` to `0` so the events come in in real-time as opposed to with a 250 millisecond delay.

Unfortunately, `CGSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval` is marked as deprecated in Snow Leopard.

The alternative is `CGEventSourceSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval(CGEventSourceRef source, CFTimeInterval seconds);` https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGEventSourceSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval

```
-(void) mouseMovement:(CGEventRef) newUserMouseMovement
{
    //Move cursor to new position
    CGSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval(0.0); //Deprecated in OS X 10.6
    CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(NSPointToCGPoint(newMousePosition));
    CGSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval(0.25); //Deprecated in OS X 10.6

    //--OR--//

    CGEventSourceRef source = ???;
    CGEventSourceSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval(source, 0.0);
    CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(NSPointToCGPoint(newMousePosition));
    CGEventSourceSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval(source, 0.25);
}
```

I can't get the latter method to work.

So I guess my question is how do I get the `CGEventSourceRef` required for that function?

Is it the event source for the user's normal mouse movement? Or for my manual warping of the cursor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Event sources don't seem to be explained anywhere, and no one knows how to use them.

```
CGPoint warpPoint = CGPointMake(42, 42);
CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(warpPoint);
CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition(true);
```

Call CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition( true ) immediately after a warp call to make the Quartz events system drop the delay for this specific warp.

Answer (score 3):

Did you ever solve this problem?

Have you tried using CGEventCreateSourceFromEvent(...) to create your CGEventSourceRef from a CGEventRef?

Comment: I was unable to find the `CGEventSourceRef` for the warp. The apple docs state the warp works "without generating or posting an event", so I'm not sure if it even has a source. From the answer I just accepted, though, 'CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition(true);' works with warp!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem of wanting an alternative to the deprecated `CGSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval` to use in conjunction with `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition` and this worked in C++:

```
CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate(CGEventSourceStateID::kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState);
CGEventSourceSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval(source, 0);
CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(CGPointMake(x, y));
CFRelease(source);
```